# How to change graphics options for Intel chipsets?

Tags: 12.10, graphics, intel, steam, 3d

I have Acer Aspire 5349 with some integrated Intel GPU. On Windows I could just open an Intel program in which I could change my graphical settings like colors, but also 3D settings for improving performance/quality.

I'm talking about this http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/img/cs030506_image2_large.jpg

And I desperately need it here on Ubuntu, to which I moved yesterday, because I am experiencing some graphical bugs at CSS on Steam. If there is no such program/equivalent then I would be okay with some console commands but please be brief- I am quite new to Ubuntu, so I'm happy for just remembering the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut!

Comment: You are probably using open source drivers that come with Ubuntu by default. Check out the drivers that you can get directly from Intel: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads The one on the top is the latest (1.0.2). Choose 32 or 64 bit version depending on what version of Ubuntu you installed.